# Switching field of study from computer science to GIS in the post graduate level

Tags: graduate-school

I have a B.Sc. in CS, but I want to further in the GIS (geographical information system) line. I am thinking I'd have to do some sort of post-graduate diploma in GIS, before I can go for a M.Sc., which is necessary to hit my mark, seemingly...

I need your guidance about this case.

Thank you very much

Comment: GIS = geographic information system? PGD = preimplementation genetic diagnosis?

Comment: @GEdgar: I guess: PGD = Postgraduate Diploma

Comment: yes, GIS=geographic information system and PGD=postgraduate diploma.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment with authority on your specific case, but some GIS masters courses may not assume much GIS-specific prior knowledge. You should probably have an interest in mapping, cartography or spatial data, and - since you are coming from a CS direction - in databases or spatial computing; but interest does not necessarily mean in-depth knowledge.

I think my advice would be "find a course that interests you, and discuss it with the person in charge of admissions".

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily...

Transition of CS students to other majors could be easier than the others in some cases. There are a great deal of ***computational*** projects within the science and engineering, could which be done, as well as possible, by the fellows who have deep ideas about the computation and implementation of simulated complex systems. As an example, I know a graduate of CS, who did changed his major to chemistry, to work on the simulation of an electro-chemical quantum reaction. He is really successful to handle the case, truly.

In such cases, one could assert that the target person might need to work hard, firstly, to construct the desired seminal background for collaboration in the new field, but this stuff is not often too tough for determined people, considerably; and the consequences would be noticeable, as the computational aspects of the project would be progressed.

So, if you are going to work on such computational subjects within your target field (GIS, or something), you better ***prepare a coherent SoP and assert on your goal within that. Then, your CS background would not be considered as an irrelevant background, but a to-the-point one, probably.***

Best